# Can I cure Hert's vampirism?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I’ve just finished the Dawnguard quest lines and decided to do some free roaming again.
I went to Half-Moon Mill and Hert could be seen working at the mill. She was facing away from me; as I approached she said I could cut some wood, turned to face me and, horror of horrors, she was a vampire!

I didn’t engage in any conversation for fear of activating some vampire-ish response and have Lydia cut her down. We just left the area in the hope of finding a cure, even a console command.

Hert is one of my favourite non-follower NPCs so I don’t want to kill her, but I can’t leave her as she is. Can I cure her?

I am playing on PC.

I want to thank you for your efforts and this is just a report of what happened in the hope someone can see what I’m doing wrong.

IF I use setrace nordrace her face changes slightly still looks vampiry not like Hert but not as much, and becomes an unmoving mask she talks but her mouth doesn’t move.
I then tried the bat file which seems to work but I did get a few spells that don’t apply to Hert. But no change to the face.
I reverted to a previous save and tried again by running the bat file first and then the setrace and I thought it had worked better as she could still talk and her moth moved but still looked vampiry not her old self. That is until I saved and reloaded and I was back to the solid mask again.
I have gone back to a save before I started this in the hope it can be fixed in future

I don’t really care that she a Vampire as long as she gets her old normal (not Vampire) Face back hopefully whatever Dawnguard does to make her look like a vampire can be undone

I have since found that changing Hert from Nord-Vampire to Nord in the construction set works and she recovers her Nord face.

Comment: fyi Hert was always a vampire

Answer (score 2):

With help from cyrus224 at Nexus Forums:

Walk up to Hert and press the ~ key at the top left of your keyboard to open the Console.

Click her, then type the commands listed below.

Or you can copy and paste the code into Notepad.

Scripts must be in the same folder as TESV.exe

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\skyrim
```

To execute a script type the following command into the Console:

```
BAT scriptname
```

where scriptname = the name of the script file

Example: `Bat VampireCureHert`

How to Cure a Player or NPC with Vampirism

Choose a RaceCode. Don't execute this command if you want them to continue looking like a Vampire (or you could execute this code just to change how Hert appears and NOT cure her).

```
SetRace NordRace
```

Then you need to run all of this code, which is why it is suggested to do it in Notepad.

```
AddToFaction 000C4DE0 -1
AddToFaction 0002EB13 -1
AddToFaction 00046281 -1
AddToFaction 00027242 -1
RemovePerk 0010F1EC
RemovePerk 000F5B56
RemovePerk 000CF02C
RemoveSpell 000F5B54
RemoveSpell 000ED0AA
RemoveSpell 00107AA1
RemoveSpell 000F5B58
RemoveSpell 000F5B59
RemoveSpell 000F5B5A
RemoveSpell 000F5B5B
RemoveSpell 0008D5C3
RemoveSpell 0008D5C7
RemoveSpell 000ED0A9
RemoveSpell 00088821
RemoveSpell 000ED097
RemoveSpell 0010F1E7
RemoveSpell 000ED0A8
RemoveSpell 0002E1C3
RemoveSpell 000ED099
RemoveSpell 000ED09D
RemoveSpell 000ED09E
RemoveSpell 0010FB30
RemoveSpell 000F5B5C
RemoveSpell 000EA077
RemoveSpell 000EA078
RemoveSpell 000EA079
RemoveSpell 000EA07A
RemoveSpell 000EA07B
RemoveSpell 000C4DE2
RemoveSpell 000ED0A4
RemoveSpell 000ED0A5
RemoveSpell 000ED0A6
RemoveSpell 000ED0A7
RemoveSpell 000C4DE1
RemoveSpell 0008D5BF
RemoveSpell 0008D5C0
RemoveSpell 0008D5C1
RemoveSpell 0008D5C2
RemoveSpell 000ED0A1
RemoveSpell 000ED0A0
RemoveSpell 000ED0A2
RemoveSpell 000ED0A3
RemoveSpell 0010F1EB
RemoveSpell 0010F1EA
RemoveSpell 0010F1E9
RemoveSpell 0010F1E8
RemoveSpell 000F5B5D
RemoveSpell 000C1E8B
RemoveSpell 000ED09A
RemoveSpell 000ED09B
RemoveSpell 000ED09C
RemoveSpell 000B8780
```

Comment: Actually, this is even easier, all you need to do is the `SetRace <race>RaceVampire`.  You just need to add vampire to the end of the setrace command.  Note: I don't think this will make them crave blood.